# In azure pipeline yaml file, can PowerShell command run in bash?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

In azure pipeline anaconda [official example](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/pipelines-anaconda/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml), the lines 13~15 are shown below

```
  steps:
  - bash: echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$CONDA/bin"
    displayName: Add conda to PATH
```

I wonder is `##vso[task.prependpath]$CONDA/bin` a bash script? If not why it can run in the bash shell? Very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

> Is ##vso[task.prependpath]$CONDA/bin a bash script?

The answer is, **YES**. This is a script which both available in `Powershell` and `Bash`.

For `vso`, here it represent visual studio online which is the old name of Azure devops. And **task.prependpath** is one of `logging command`, and **logging command** is a one which used to communicate between `tasks/steps` and `agent`. The logging command can both apply in Bash and Powershell script line.

For this confusing one, it can be used to modified the `PATH` environment variable by **prepending** to the `PATH` value. Also, the next steps can use this modified `PATH` value.

*I think, this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#prependpath-prepend-a-path-to-the--path-environment-variable) would provide you a good understanding on logging command.*